# UART connected device communication only works one way

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, uart, remote-control

As the title implies, I have two Arduino devices (Uno and Mega) connected to each other over UART (the Mega is hardware UART, the Uno is software UART); I need the Mega to send a command to the Uno, the Uno to perform the command, then the Uno to report back to the Mega when it has finished the task. In this way, I want to implement asynchronous programming to control various light patterns as well as several motors (code not shown, it is unnecessary as the light control is in an isolated segment) without needing any firmware hacking. Sending commands from the Mega to the Uno works, but the reverse is not true, and even polling waitloops do not work. Note that if I send the "affirm" command repeatedly for infinity, but then I hang the code in the Uno and the Mega has no way to stop the barrage; it starts receiving likely random bytes.
My code for the Mega is bulky and multi-file so I can't send the entire thing, but here is the control code:

```cpp
lights::showRow(Serial1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2);
lights::waitUntilFinished(Serial1);
delay(500);
lights::clear(Serial1);
lights::waitUntilFinished(Serial1);
lights::chantO(Serial1);
lights::waitUntilFinished(Serial1);
lights::showRow(Serial1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2);
lights::waitUntilFinished(Serial1);
delay(500);
lights::clear(Serial1);
lights::waitUntilFinished(Serial1);
lights::chantX(Serial1);
lights::waitUntilFinished(Serial1);
```

These commands are implemented by:

```cpp
namespace lights{
  boll ready = false;
  boll helloSent = false;
  void chantO(HardwareSerial coms){
    coms.write(1);
  }
  void chantX(HardwareSerial coms){
    coms.write(2);
  }
  void showRow(HardwareSerial coms, uint8_t x1, uint8_t y1, uint8_t x2, uint8_t y2, uint8_t x3, uint8_t y3){
    coms.write(3);
    coms.write(x1);
    coms.write(y1);
    coms.write(x2);
    coms.write(y2);
    coms.write(x3);
    coms.write(y3);
  }
  void clear(HardwareSerial coms){
    coms.write(4);
  }
  void waitUntilFinished(HardwareSerial coms){
    while (coms.available() == 0){};
    Serial.println("Done.");
    // It can't say anything but "affirmed", so we can save some code by not checking.
  }
}
```

The light code:

```cpp
/* To make life easy, I will include a wiring map. Change as needed.
 *  Note that each ring is 24 pixels, and is labeled with the first-position to access it. The next one is obviously going to be the final point.
 ____     ____     ____  
/48  \___/72  \   /192 \
\____/   \____/   \____/  
 |___     |___     |___  
/24  \   /96  \   /168 \  
\____/   \____/   \____/  
 |___     |___     |___  
/0   \   /120 \___/144 \_____[END]  
\____/   \____/   \____/  
 |
 |
[CONTROLLER]

*/


#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#ifdef __AVR__
  #include <avr/power.h>
#endif
#define PIN       6
#define NUMPIXELS 216
#define DELAYVAL 500

Adafruit_NeoPixel pixels(NUMPIXELS, PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);
SoftwareSerial coms(9, 8);
int white = pixels.Color(255, 255, 255);
int red = pixels.Color(255, 0, 0);

int getPixel(uint8_t x, uint8_t y, uint8_t num){
  if (x == 0){
    return 48 - (y * 24) + num;
  }
  else if (x == 1){
    return 72 + (y * 24) + num;
  }
  else if (x == 2){
    return 192 - (y * 24) + num;
  }
}

void setRing(uint8_t x, uint8_t y, int color){
  for (int i = 0; i < 24; i ++){
    pixels.setPixelColor(getPixel(x, y, i), color);
  }
}

void setup(){
  pinMode(9, INPUT);
  pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
  coms.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pixels.begin();
  pixels.setBrightness(205); // 0.8 * 256 = 204.8; thus this is 80% power. Only 6 can be lit up before you have issues.
}

void loop(){
  if (coms.available() > 0){
    uint8_t d = coms.read();
    Serial.println("He talkin' me");
    Serial.print("He say ");
    Serial.println(d);
    switch (d){
      case 1:
        for (uint8_t x = 0; x < 2; x ++){
          setRing(0, 1, white);
          setRing(1, 0, white);
          setRing(2, 1, white);
          setRing(1, 2, white);
          pixels.show();
          delay(500);
          pixels.clear();
          pixels.show();
          delay(500);
        }
        break;
      case 2:
        for (uint8_t x = 0; x < 2; x ++){
          setRing(0, 0, white);
          setRing(2, 2, white);
          setRing(2, 0, white);
          setRing(0, 2, white);
          setRing(1, 1, white);
          pixels.show();
          delay(500);
          pixels.clear();
          delay(500);
        }
        break;
      case 3:
        Serial.println("Hello, World");
        setRing(coms.read(), coms.read(), red);
        setRing(coms.read(), coms.read(), red);
        setRing(coms.read(), coms.read(), red);
        pixels.show();
        break;
      case 4:
        pixels.clear();
        pixels.show();
        break;
    }
    coms.write(1);
  }
}
```

Comment: upload softwareSerial example sketch into both arduinos ... use hardware serial on the mega ... test connectivity between the two arduinos

Comment: You need to pass your HardwareSerial parameters by reference to prevent object copying.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing your `HardwareSerial` (`Serial1`) objects by value. That means that the object is copied, which is not good - it breaks the connection between the incoming data buffer and the interrupt that loads the RX ringbuffer.

Instead you must either pass *by reference* or *by pointer*.  Personally I prefer pointers because it's what I am used to using, but you can use either.

For example:

```cpp
  void waitUntilFinished(HardwareSerial &coms){ // <--- note the &
    while (coms.available() == 0){};
    Serial.println("Done.");
    // It can't say anything but "affirmed", so we can save some code by not checking.
  }
```

I would also consider changing this from a namespace to a class and passing the serial object you wish to use as a parameter to the constructor and storing the pointer to it in the class - then you only need ever pass it once and then use that pointer from then on. It would just simplify your code and clean things up somewhat.